Perfect strategy in Liar's Dice?
The variant of the game I'm thinking of goes like this. Each player rolls 6 dice, and only they can see the result. Then, an arbitrary starting player makes a bet "there are at least x dice of type y among all our dice".
Then, any of the other players can call BS. If they do, the game ends, and if their bet was correct (there were x or more dice with y eyes) the player that made the bet wins, if not the person that calls BS wins.
If no one calls BS, the next person has to make a bet, but they have to either increase x, or keep x constant and increase y. So after someone bets "2 dice with 3 eyes", the next can bet "2 dice with 4 eyes" or "3 dice with 1 eye", but not "1 dice with 3 eyes" or "2 dice with 2 eyes"
I'm trying to figure out whether there exists an optimal strategy for this game. Seems like the game should be simple enough to be tractible, but I don't know. In the first round, you can estimate the probability of a bet being correct using elementary probability theory, but when you take into account information communicated by other players decision, it becomes harder.

Since this is a bluffing game, it's not even clear that one can estimate probabilities in the very first round—it depends on the strategy of the speaker given the particular outcome of their dice.

There's been a little bit of analysis of Liar's Dice using game theory, including this article in Towards Data Science by Thomas Ahle. One of the biggest problems of determining the Nash equilibrium is that the game, while simple, has quite a big state space filled with many unknowns and dependencies (e.g. you potentially need to keep track of such esoteric values as "the probability that player 4 sees 3 threes and 2 sixes, given that player 2 bid 1 four").
Thomas previously calculated some exact Nash equilibria for various 1v1 iterations of the game, but for higher player count he went with a machine learning approach. The result is an algorithm that you could, in theory, turn into a descriptive strategy, although it probably wouldn't be a very readable one (and would also be probabilistic, in the sense that rather than saying "always make this choice in this scenario" instead says "in this scenario, draw a random number and follow this huge look-up table to determine which choice to make").
From setting his algorithm up against real people, he found that it has an advantage of about 23 to 48 Elo points above its human opponents, which is meaningful but not huge (for example, in chess, the various Master and Grandmaster ranks typically have 100 Elo points between them), and he suggests that the randomness of the game typically contributes towards 80% of the win rate, meaning that even a perfect strategy is not going to have a lossless record.
